# For loop evaluation order

Tags: python

I was looking into the `all` and `any` functions to see their guarantees about order.

For example, the documentation states that the `any` function is equivalent to:

```py
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

However, when running the following code:

```py
a = 1
any([a == 1, a[1] == 1])
```

I would expect the second expression to not be evaluated and, thus, would return True. Instead, the second line throws `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. I initially believed that this was some inconsistency in the documentation but, indeed, when running with the `for` loop version, the result is the same.

My question is, how does it throw the exception, if it should not evaluate the second expression by returning `True` early? I thought that python only checked those errors when running the expressions.

Changing to

```py
a = 1
any([a == 1, print('hello world')])
```

Also evaluates the `print` in both versions. Can anyone shine some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Note: using python 3.8.10 and interaction was performed in the python shell.

Comment: When you create a list, all the elements of the list have to be evaluted.

Comment: You are creating a list that you are passing to `any()`.  The `any()` method cannot be called until the list is created.  That's why both expressions are being ran.  That's in the list creation.

Comment: Duh, what was I thinking? Thank you

Comment: However, could we build a generator object that would not be instantly evaluated? The confusion came from comparing this with `if` statements short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @JoãoDavid, yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Barmar said, all the elements inside of the list must be evaluated when the list is created, to create something similar to that but lazy you could do:

```
def it():
    yield print(1)
    yield print(2)
    yield True
    yield print(3)
    
print(any(it()))
```

With output:

```
1
2
True
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew the answer would be something with `yield` but did not reach a solution, that is perfect :)

Comment: @JoãoDavid, You are welcome :)